# How to round down a float using import math

Tags: python, rounding

I have a variable that is a float, and I can't find out how to round it down.

I did a google search and it said I should use trunc, but trunc didn't work for me.

Comment: `math.floor` works

Comment: Odd you didn't find it since googling `round down a float using import math python` points you to [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor)

Comment: you may find it helpful to use `dir(math)` or `help(math)` to explore modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you always want to round down and are getting positive floats, just use `int()` .. otherwise you can use `math.floor()`, which can handle negative floats too

```py
>>> math.floor(3.99)
3
>>> int(-0.1)
0
>>> int(-1.2)
-1
>>> math.floor(-1.2)
-2
```